# Creating Pac-Man.

Tags: modeling

I'm learning Blender and have done some tutorials amd now I'm trying to create my own scene. I'm trying to create a simple 3D-model of Pac-Man with only black eyes and the mouth but it's more difficult than I thought. The trouble is the mouth. I've seen some tutorials using boolean modifiers with a simple triangle shape on a sphere, but I get a jagged edge on the mouth. What would be the easiest way to create my Pac-Man model without a jagged edge on the mouth? I saw Blender Guru's tutorial on the anvil where he cleaned up his mesh after using Boolean, but it's a lot of work with a sphere and possible a lot of N-gons and other weird shapes. Any good ideas? I'm trying to recreate this simple model in 3D. [image]

Comment: Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28995/trying-to-create-pacman

Comment: You can do this without poor aliasing by using curves, but I can't answer it currently due to the question being closed. Sorry.

Comment: Better answer is at https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8648/rigging-a-pac-man-like-character

Answer (score 1):

I would make a uv sphere, cut out the remaining vertices of the mouth and then unite everything .. I would add an additional uv sphere to the eyes and apply a mirror modifier. and for the black edges in the render I would use freestyle

[you can download  the file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jYq7Im1pFXMcrv7flVR2iPPvUmB6oWKE/view?usp=sharing)

[image: wire]

[image: packman result]
[image: packman result 2]

If you want to animate the mouth maybe the process will be different

Comment: I believe that I have an answer that uses curves to allow animating of this shape using curves instead of mesh objects. I'll wait for it to re-open to post the answer.